# NTDLL symbols available but !address does not work

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, ntdll

I'm trying to do basic debugging with WinDbg but I'm stuck at the beginning since my environment cannot find the symbols for `ntdll` and those are essential for the `!address` command:

```
0:000> !address
No symbols for ntdll. Cannot continue.
```

The weird thing is that using `lm` I can see that the debugger aware of the symbol file! So why it can't use this file? This file was imported using `symchk` utility so it supposed to be the right symbol file.

Here is the `command` window output:

```
0:000> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> lm
start    end        module name
007b0000 007db000   notepad    (no symbols)           
71b50000 71d5f000   COMCTL32   (deferred)             
747b0000 747ba000   CRYPTBASE   (deferred)             
747c0000 747e0000   SspiCli    (deferred)             
747e0000 748ff000   ucrtbase   (deferred)             
749c0000 74a39000   advapi32   (deferred)             
74a40000 74afb000   RPCRT4     (deferred)             
74db0000 74fac000   KERNELBASE   (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\wkernelbase.pdb\8BC9719D7B1E26272FB1CB98D403792C1\wkernelbase.pdb
75120000 7517f000   bcryptPrimitives   (deferred)             
75200000 75276000   sechost    (deferred)             
75330000 75347000   win32u     (deferred)             
757a0000 7585f000   msvcrt     (deferred)             
76430000 7658a000   gdi32full   (deferred)             
76590000 76727000   USER32     (deferred)             
76730000 767ac000   msvcp_win   (deferred)             
768c0000 769a0000   KERNEL32   (deferred)             
76aa0000 76b24000   shcore     (deferred)             
76c50000 76ec6000   combase    (deferred)             
76fb0000 76fd1000   GDI32      (deferred)             
76ff0000 7718a000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D85FCE08D56038E2C69B69F29E11B5EE1\wntdll.pdb
```

You can see that the location of the symbol file is identified (`lm` command output) But it claims no symbol are found.

More interesting, WinDbg can show me the symbols of functions inside `ntdll` binary:

```
0:000> x ntdll!*Virtual*
76ff44c0          ntdll!RtlpQueryReadVirtualMemory (void)
76f9bcc7          ntdll!RtlpSecMemFreeVirtualMemory (void)
76fb2df0          ntdll!NtLockVirtualMemory (<no parameter info>)
76fb1fa0          ntdll!ZwQueryVirtualMemory (<no parameter info>)
76fb2bd0          ntdll!NtFlushVirtualMemory (<no parameter info>)
76fb36f0          ntdll!ZwSetInformationVirtualMemory (<no parameter info>)
...
```

But still, whenever I try to use the `!address` command I have the same error.

Comment: `lm` lists the modules it is aware of, it doesn't mean that it has loaded all the symbols, you need to add a path to the symbols, see related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983523/windbg-windows-symbols?rq=1 did you do this?

Comment: Yes. I just about to edit the Q and show that using `x ntdll!*` works, but still the `!address` command gives this "no symbols for ntdll" error. This is really weird.

Comment: You could have a duff cache, did you try `.symfix;.reload`? You could also try the suggestion on point 4. here: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=164 basically to see if your pdb is corrupt

Comment: Yes I tried. Please check the edit. Thanks

Comment: what is your OS version and Windbg version? Looks very odd to me, does this happen every time or is it temporal? You can calling `.reload /o /f` to override the current cache

Comment: Its Windows 10 home 64-bit running on VM (Virtual Box). WinDbg from Windows 10 SDK.
Yes its happen every time. It is look odd to me too. I tried `.reload /o /f` but it didn't work. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207758/discussion-between-z-e-nir-and-edchum-reinstate-monica).